# IOS: How can I animate a change in indentationLevel?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableView where some rows are indented using indentationLevel.  Cells have the style UITableViewCellStyleValue1, so I get the textLabel indented but not the detailTextLabel.  Sometimes I want to change the indentation of a row so the text moves left or right.  Setting indentationLevel works, but the text jumps suddenly: how can I have it animate smoothly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works - changing the indent by indentDelta:

```
CGRect frame = cell.textLabel.frame;
frame.origin.x += indentDelta * cell.indentationWidth;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    cell.textLabel.frame = frame;
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    cell.indentationLevel = cell.indentationLevel + indentDelta;
}];
```

First the labels are smoothly scrolled to where I want them, then the rows are repainted with the correct truncation and left with indentationLevel correct so they paint correctly if they are regenerated, e.g. if clicked on to select.